# Determine Elasticsearch Minor Version Using RPM Repository

Tags: elasticsearch, rpm

I've used [Installing from the RPM repository](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/rpm.html#rpm-repo) to install Elasticsearch. The last version of Elasticsearch has been installed by the `yum install elasticsearch` command.

What should I have to do if I want to install another minor version of Elasticsearch? (For example installing 7.3.0 instead of 7.3.1)

Answer (score 2):

```
# yum install <package name>-<version info>
```

But you need to know the release version as well.
So for example, if the ES package is `elasticsearch-7.6.2-1.rpm`,the command will be:

```
# yum install elasticsearch-7.6.2-1
```

You can find the release version by invoking:

```
$ yum info <package-name>
```